# How do I create a range of words to iterate through as hyperparameters?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

To create a range of numbers we do:

```
numbers = np.arange(1,15,1)
```

What should we do to create a range of words?:

```
linkage_all = (ward, complete, average, single)
```

I want to define these words and then iterate through the clustering algorithm:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(linkage=linkage_all).fit(X)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

```
linkage_all = ("ward", "complete", "average", "single")
for linkage in linkage_all:
    clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(linkage=linkage).fit(X)
    # do stuff with the clustering object
```

Comment: instead of `("ward", "complete", "average", "single")` put `["ward", "complete", "average", "single"]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to generate random words for testing here is a package for it
[RandomWords](https://pypi.org/project/RandomWords/0.1.5/)

you can get random words like this

```py
words = rw.random_words(count=10)
print(words)
## ['runs', 'experience', 'comments', 'freedom', 'permit', 'honks', 'pins', 'texts', 'grant', 'fathers']
```